# Customize camera in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, camera, layar

I have used Layar Sdk in my android app. I have successfully integrated Library to it.

Now i want to customise camera and add a info button to it.

I have used below code:-

```
String oauthKey = "xxx";
String oauthSecret = "xxx";
LayarSDK.initialize(this, oauthKey, oauthSecret);
layarSDKClient client = new layarSDKClient(LayerLaunch.this);
LayarSDK.startLayarActivity(this, client);
```

I got from support that it is possible by LayarSDKFragment class.But i can not get it how.

Thanks